# Angularjs and Asp.net MVC - angular desn't get values from input type hidden

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a list to a view as hidden type and get those values ​​with the angular

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfIds.Count;i++)   
{
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="model.ManagersId" value="@Model.ListOfIds[i]" />

    // or

    <input type="hidden" ng-model="model.ManagersId" ngvalue="@Model.ListOfIds[i]" />

    // or

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListOfIds[i], new { @ng_model="model.ManagersId"}) 
}
```

In my angular controller I have something of the type

```
$scope.GetValues= function () {
    console.log($scope.model);
}
```

I can get the value of all other fields **except the hidden type**. 
When the function is called I have something of the type:

```
Object {Info: "A", Info: "B"}
```

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [ng-Init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to set the value in the `hiddenfield`

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfIds.Count;i++)   
{
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="model.ManagersId"  ng-init="model.ManagersId = @Model.ListOfIds[i]" />

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Usman... I change my markupt to:

    for(int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfIds.Count;i++)   
    {
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="model.ManagersId[@i]"  ng-init="model.ManagersId[@i] = @Model.ListOfIds[i]" />
    }

... and it worked.